# Dynamic Loading of Data Via Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am new to AJAX and I am trying to load some data when clicked on a button to a modal, But the expected result is not being rendered and there are no errors thrown in the Developers Console.

The code AJAX code is as follows,

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(document).on('click','.edit_data', function(){  
    var employee_id = $(this).attr("User_ID");  
    $.ajax({  
        url:"fetchuser.php",  
        method:"POST",  
        data:{employee_id:employee_id},  
        dataType:"json",  
        success:function(data){  
            $('#floatingInputname').val(data.floatingInputname);    
            $('#add_data_Modal').modal('show');  
        }  
    });  
}); 
});
</script>
```

And the fetchuser.php code is as follows,

```
<?php
include 'config.php';
if (isset($_POST['employee_id'])) {
   $query = "SELECT * FROM gusers WHERE User_ID = '".$_POST['employee_id']."'";
   $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
   $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
   echo json_encode($row);
}
?>
```

The HTML table structure where I have a button to be clicked for the modal with the data to load is as follows,

```
<table class="table" id="myTable" style="width: 100%;">
<thead>
<th scope="col">Image</th>
<th scope="col">Name</th>
<th scope="col">NIC</th>
<th scope="col">Contact</th>
<th scope="col">Role</th>
<th scope="col"></th>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
$queryguser = "SELECT * FROM `gusers`";
$gusersresult = mysqli_query($conn,$queryguser);
if ($gusersresult->num_rows>0) {
while ($gusersrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($gusersresult)) {
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td scope="row">
    <?php
    if (empty($gusersrow['Image'])|| $gusersrow['Image']==null) {
        ?>
        <img src="img/question (1).png" alt="No Profile" style="width:75px; height:75px; border-    
radius:20px;">
        <?php
    }
    else{
        echo '<img src="data:image;base64,'.base64_encode($gusersrow['Image']).'" alt="Profile Image" 
style="width:75px; height:75px; border-radius:50%;">';
    }
    ?>
    </td>
    
    <td contenteditable="true" data-old_value="<?php $gusersrow['User_Name']; ?>" 
onBlur="inlineedit(this,'User_Name','<?php echo $gusersrow["User_ID"]; ?>')" 
onClick="highlightEdit(this);">
    <?php echo $gusersrow["User_Name"]; ?>
    </td>
    <td contenteditable="true" data-old_value="<?php $gusersrow['User_NIC']; ?>" 
onBlur="inlineedit(this,'User_NIC','<?php echo $gusersrow["User_ID"]; ?>')" 
onClick="highlightEdit(this);">
    <?php echo $gusersrow["User_NIC"]; ?>
    </td>
    
    <td contenteditable="true" data-old_value="<?php $gusersrow['User_Contact']; ?>" 
onBlur="inlineedit(this,'User_Contact','<?php echo $gusersrow["User_ID"]; ?>')" 
onClick="highlightEdit(this);">
    <?php echo $gusersrow["User_Contact"]; ?>
    </td>
    <td contenteditable="true" data-old_value="<?php $gusersrow['Role']; ?>" 
 onBlur="inlineedit(this,'Role','<?php echo $gusersrow["User_ID"]; ?>')" 
 onClick="highlightEdit(this);">
    <?php echo $gusersrow["Role"]; ?>
    </td>
    
    <td scope="row" class="text-center"><input type="button" name="edit" value="Edit" id="<?php echo                         
  $gusersrow["User_ID"]; ?>" class="btn btn-info btn-xs edit_data" /></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}
}else{
echo "No Records Found";
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

And the Modal i want the data to be displayed

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModaluserupdate" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"     
aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Update User Data</h5>
<button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<form action="" method="post">
<div class="row" style="width:100%;">
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="form-floating mb-3">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="floatingInputname">
<label for="floatingInputname">Name</label>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="form-floating mb-3">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="floatingInputnic">
<label for="floatingInputnic">NIC</label>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Further to this i have the following JS scripts loaded in my `<head>` tag

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: There must be an error if not working correctly. please check it out in the network, not in the developer console. Move to inspect than to network after that reload again check there is there any error or not?

Comment: Check out in the Network tab your request, see what is being returned and determine if the problem is upstream from the ajax (php) of downstream (js).

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: **Danger**: You are using an ancient version of jQuery and then overriding it with another almost as ancient version of jQuery, both of which have known security issues. Load jQuery **once** and make it the **most recent version**.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] (emphasis on the minimal). Do some debugging. Test to make sure the function which triggers the Ajax function is called. Log something in the callback so you know it is being triggered. Log the value you are using.